# Timer 1 COMPA ISR - default behaviour?

Tags: interrupt, atmega328

I'm creating a LCD frequency generator.

When `TIMER1` reaches a set value, it's set to toggle Pin 9 (via `OC1A`).

Accidentally, I left the `TIMER1` "interrupt on compare match A" enabled, but never defined the `TIMER1_COMPA_vect` interrupt vector.

This made the Uno reset itself - but not running through the bootloader, just the program part - whenever `TIMER1_COMPA_vect` would've been called.

Once I defined the ISR, even without it having any content, it would run as expected.

**Is there a default content for ISRs, which resets the device / starts just after the bootloader? Shouldn't the compiler detect a completely missing ISR?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler cannot detect a missing ISR since it is very difficult, in
the general case, to tell whether any particular interrupt-enable bit
has been set by the program.

The avr-libc library does indeed provide a “catch-all” ISR and, as
stated by the manual,

> the default action is to reset the device by jumping to the reset
>   vector.

If you don't like this behavior, you can override this catch-all with
your own, [as explained in the manual](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html#details) (search for “Catch-all
interrupt vector”).

Comment: Very interesting, that solves my confusion - thank you.